# How do I add MVVM Light to an existing project?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

We're working with the ModernUI for WPF framework to create a new WPF app. So that's how we created the application in VS 2013. Now I want to add MVVM Light to that same project. Previously I had downloaded the MVVM Light Toolkit. When I open up the project in VS 2013 and try to add MVVM Light I see that it is installed in Extensions and Updates, but I cannot add a reference to it in the project.

I downloaded version 5.2 of MVVM Light.

Comment: why can't you reference it ? 
FYI , ever heard of nuget ?

Comment: Yes I've heard of NuGet. However, when I look it up in NuGet, NuGet doesn't allow me to install it.

Comment: NuGet thinks its already installed, but it isn't. I've not installed it and it isn't in my project's references.

Comment: than remove it via nuget and install again

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong. I was trying to do it only through Tools | Extensions and Updates. I should have right-mouse button clicked on the References folder in the project and then select Manage NuGet Packages. Thanks for your help, eran.